# Where are tex/mactex binaries after brew install mactex

Tags: homebrew, macos

As can be seen: `mactex` was installed successfully:

```
==> Installing Cask mactex
==> Running installer for mactex; your password may be necessary.
==> Package installers may write to any location; options such as --appdir are ignored.
Password:




==> installer: Package name is MacTeX-2017
==> installer: Upgrading at base path /
==> installer: The upgrade was successful.
  mactex was successfully installed!
```

*Where* is it however..

```
21:22:37/hw6 $which tex
21:23:35/hw6 $which mactex
```

Comment: `brew cask` installs binaries into `/usr/local/Caskroom/` . Could you check that?

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek  Well there's a `/usr/local/Caskroom/mactex/20170524/mactex-20170524.pkg`  .. but  there are no binaries *anywhere* (did a `find / -name tex` and also `find / name mactex` ..)

Comment: Mactex is a graphical application, so probably "MacTeX.app" is located somewhere in `/Applications/`. And the binary is probably in `MacTeX.app/Contents/MacOS/`

Comment: oh there's a `TeX` app .. let's see what's in there..

Comment: i'ts `TexLive` which is something different..  I can't get any joy on `Tex` it seems

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At the time of writing (June 17th, 2018) running:

```
brew cask install mactex
```

will install MacTeX-2018 and

```
which tex
```

gives

```
/Library/TeX/texbin/tex
```

Comment: doesn't work like that for me.  same problem as op.

Comment: oh, after starting a new shell it's there.

Comment: As of September 2018 it now works (as mentioned in my own answer that had not been the case in April).

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this is answer is unrelated to the issue the OP had, but I found the question while I was having a similar issue. While reinstalling MacTeX, I noticed this message:

```
==> Caveats
You must restart your terminal window for the installation of MacTex CLI tools to take effect.
Alternatively, Bash and Zsh users can run the command:

  eval "$(/usr/libexec/path_helper)"
```

Sure enough, after running that command, I found `tex` in my path:

```
$ type tex
tex is /Library/TeX/texbin/tex
```

And starting a new terminal window also solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

In  April I had installed/reinstalled multiple times without success.

Bu I reinstalled via `brew cask reinstall mactex`  in Sept 2018 and the issues no longer appeared: `mactex` worked.  Maybe something were resolved in the binaries.